# Swagger-editor don't work local refs when it installed locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I'm new on swagger.

I've installed Swagger on Ubuntu 14.04 server two times and always get same error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"` in Chrome and `"TypeError: async is undefined async.map(_.keys(remoteRefs), function (refPtr, callback)"` in Firefox when i'm use `$ref` in any kind of document, include examples.

All other functions work's fine, problem reproduce only when I try use any reference

- My node version: v0.10.38
- Npm versiton: 1.4.28
- Swagger version is latest

Comment: What do you mean by installing Swagger? Are you trying to run Swagger Editor locally?

Comment: i've run swagger on remote vps, and acces to it from my computer

Comment: just now i've cloned swagger-editor on my pc, started it, and still get same error with my file and any examles that has at least one $ref

Comment: If you can share your Swagger spec or make a minimal swagger spec that can reproduce this issue I might be able to help you

Comment: I have this same problem. I see these errors in my console even just when it launches with `npm start`. It also happens when trying to load any example files.